# Prebuilt Python package on OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, setuptools

Ok, I want to create a pre-built Python package which contains a C module.  That is, at the end of it I want to have a tarball which contains everything needed to use my module and is pip install-able, ie at the end I can do a:

```
pip install whatevertarballgetsproduced.tar.gz
```

and mylibrary will be available.  It also needs to be virtual environment friendly.

My current directory structure is:

```
project/
    + setup.py
    + mylibrary/
        + __init__.py
        + mylibrary.py
        + _mylibrary.so
    + README
```

That is, the compiled C library is in `_mylibrary.so`.  The C source from which this file is derived is *NOT* to be included in the tarball.  I am also doing this on OSX (Lion). `mylibrary.py` simply contains Python wrappers to the C library code.

How do I achieve this?  I thought about doing a `python setup.py bdist` but this isn't really what I want (unless I'm missing something the tarball produced by that isn't pip install-able).

For the sake of completion, my setup.py looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='mylibrary_py3mac',
    version='0.1.1',
    description='My library which is tied to OSX & Python 3',
    long_description=open('README').read(),
    packages=['mylibrary'],
    classifiers = [
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
        'Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
    ],
)
```

Note, I don't plan on distributing this tarball publicly, it is for internal deployment purposes only (hence why I don't care about it being precompiled, or tied to OSX only).

Answer (score 0):

Adam, have you tried `setup.py bdist_egg`?

It will produce an egg file that can be installed using `easy_install` (not with `pip`, unfortunately).

Also, it looks like your project is missing `mylibrary/__init__.py`.

Once you add the missing "init" file, I am curious to know if `setup.py` will be smart enough to include the "so" file into the resulting egg file. There's a chance you have to prod it somehow (I myself haven't had a reason to deal with ".so" Python extensions, so I don't know how to).

In the following example, I have `gevent-1.0b2-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg` that was built using its `setup.py bdist_egg`. I've placed it into `pypi/` directory under the current directory. I know that it happens to have other dependencies that I've also strategically placed into the same `pypi/` directory.

```
easy_install --allow-hosts=None \
             --find-links=pypi/ \
             --always-unzip \
             pypi/gevent-1.0b2-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg
```

Your case is simpler, because you don't seem to have any extra dependencies.
So you'd do something like:

```
easy_install --always-unzip \
             dist/mylibrary_py3mac-0.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.4-x86_64.egg
```

Note that `dist/` directory is where built eggs files go, when `setup.py bdist_egg` is invoked.

Comment: Forgot to include the `__init__.py`, thanks for pointing that out.  To answer your question: I did try creating the egg, but as you mention .egg's don't work with Pip, and that's a key requirement for me.

Comment: When you install packages with Pip do you target a Python virtual environment or you install straight into global site-packages? In the former case, your Pip requirement maybe moot because modern `virtualenv` bundles both pip and easy_install, and these tools interoperate just fine. So if pip is missing a feature, easy_install can be used, like shown.

Comment: Both actually, in some cases I will need to target my global site-packages, and in other cases I'll be using virtual environments.  I also have a number of other dependencies which are specified in a pip requirements file, and as such it would be nice to not have to mix both `easy_install` and `pip` for package management for this project.

Comment: In that case, you're out of luck for now since `pip` doesn't support this functionality yet (it would seem).